# Connecting to remote MySQL server: edited bind-address, all permissions granted, allowed port on firewall: Still cannot connect

Tags: mysql, server

As the title describes I have gone through nearly every step to connect to this remote database. Here is what I have done:

- Bind-address is set to all zeroes in my.cnf file.
- Server owner/manager has opened it for remote connections
- Server manager has granted my user all privilges.
- I have verified port 3306 is open and listening and added an exception in my firewall for this port.

With all of these changes I still cannot connect.

I get "Error 2002: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysecrethost.something' (10060)." Every single time.

Is there any other steps of correction to make? The only thing I think it could be is my internet, since it is a public institution there may be some setting on their wifi that is preventing me from connecting, but I tested this using my phone as a hot-spot and it still failed.

Is this error saying I am not allowed to connect, or is it saying something else? SO questions/answers discuss firewall rules but I do not want to disable my firewall to test it.

Comment: Check the user "from host" property.  If your user "root" by example have a "from host" set to "localhost", you won't be able to connect remotely.

Comment: @DanielBlais where would I check this? Is this a property of the server itself or a setting on my end?

Comment: You are on Windows or linux?

Comment: Using windows yes

Comment: The "from host" is on the server end....

Comment: You can easily use Mysql Workbench.

Comment: I have been using HeidiSQL as a GUI for a while and attempted to connect that way as well, but the same error occurs.

Comment: If this is that error, you have to connect on the server, to authorize user from remote computer.